# How to save output redirect to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, io

New to **C#** and want to implement below reading from `input.txt` and write result to `output.txt`

```
myprogram.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

**my code as below**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String line = Console.ReadLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(line);
                line = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is reading from input.txt is fine, and output.txt can be created but nothing in it.

UPDATE: the rootcause is output.txt been locked by other process which is not C# language related.

Comment: You are not reading a file and you are not redirecting standard input or output so is this really the code you want to show?

Comment: @Crowcoder it read them out, console command line redirect file as input stream and output stream. Read works but write not working.

Comment: Can you show how you have redirected output?

Comment: @Crowcoder by running my application with  "myprogram.exe < input.txt > output.txt"

Comment: I see now. That should work, it works for me. Do you get any console errors?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have the output file open in something that is locking it. Make sure you don't have it open in Word or something like that.

Comment: @Crowcoder You right! it's been locked by vshost32.exe which I do not know what it is and I can write it after I close VS.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parameters = GetParameters(args);

            var inputContent = GetInputContent(parameters);

            CreateOutputFile(parameters, inputContent);

            Console.WriteLine("it's ok. Press key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void CreateOutputFile(MyProgramParameters parameters, string inputContent)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(parameters.OutputFileName, inputContent);
        }

        private static string GetInputContent(MyProgramParameters parameters)
        {
            var result = File.ReadAllText(parameters.InputFileName);

            return result;
        }

        private static MyProgramParameters GetParameters(string[] args)
        {
            CheckInputParameters(args);

            return new MyProgramParameters
            {
                InputFileName = args[0],
                OutputFileName = args[1]
            };
        }

        private static void CheckInputParameters(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("invalid parameters. For example, myProgram.exe input1.txt   output.txt");

            var inputFileName = args[0];

            if (!File.Exists(inputFileName))
                throw new IOException(string.Format("File {0} not found", inputFileName));
        }
    }

    public class MyProgramParameters
    {
        public string InputFileName { get; set; }

        public string OutputFileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is using command line redirect operators, not trying to load file paths from arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't read documentation at all. Here you have the link: [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file)

You should just do it in 2 steps:

- Read from file to `string[]`
- Write to file from `string[]`

To read use

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");
```

To write use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

Whole function would look something like this:

```
private void CopyFromFileToFile(string inputFileDest, string outputFileDest)
{
    string[] lines;
    lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(inputFileDest);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(outputFileDest, lines);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask how to read and write a file, OP is trying to use standard input/output to do it.